# Sympy simplification is broken (square roots)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, square-root, simplification

I tried this in python shell

```
>>> from sympy import sqrt
>>> sqrt((-9/10 + 6*sqrt(3)/5)**2 + (6/5 + 9*sqrt(3)/10)**2)
sqrt((-0.9 + 6*sqrt(3)/5)**2 + (1.2 + 9*sqrt(3)/10)**2)
```

and when type it in google:

[image: Google Calculator]

So how do I get numpy to give me a more simpilified result (it won't always be an int so I cant use evalf or N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things missing here:

1. You need to explicitly tell sympy to `simplify` the expression if it's something complex.
2. You should use `Rational` whenever possible, to avoid numerical inaccuraties of floating point arithmetic

All in all:

```py
>>> from sympy import Rational, simplify, sqrt
>>> simplify(sqrt((-Rational(9, 10) + Rational(6,5)*sqrt(3))**2 + (Rational(6,5) + Rational(9,10)*sqrt(3))**2))
3
```