# sympy square roots: best way to do operations on rational numbers?

Tags: python, sympy, sqrt, rational-number

Since i want square roots to be simplified, I've come across this workaround:

```
from sympy import sqrt, factor, simplify

_sqrt = sqrt
sqrt = lambda x: factor(simplify(_sqrt(x)))

# do maths operations with sqrt...
```

But it's too slow and I don't think it's the most suitable method one can use
So is there any other way to work with square roots and simplify them - automatically -

Comment: In what way do you want them simplified? SymPy already puts them in simplest form.

Comment: No it doesn't. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034086/sympy-simplification-is-broken-square-roots)

Answer (score 0):

SymPy automatically simplifies rational arguments to `sqrt`, but it is possible to write rationals in a manner such that they are not explicitly rational (as in your previous post):

```
>>> eq
sqrt((-9/10 + 6*sqrt(3)/5)**2 + (6/5 + 9*sqrt(3)/10)**2)
```

`sqrt` will only simplify an explicit *Rational* argument. Expansion of the base of the argument reveals that it is a Rational and the `sqrt` will simplify it:

```
>>> eq.base.expand()
9
>>> sqrt(9) == 3
True
```

Better than `expand` in such cases where you need to flatten an expression involving powers is the `_mexpand` function:

```
>>> from sympy.core.function import _mexpand as flat
>>> flat(eq)
3
```

Comment: So should I replace the `factor(symplify(sqrt(x)))` with `_mexpand(sqrt(x))` ?

Comment: In your lambda expression, yes. But if your `x` might have ratios of expressions then `sqrt = lambda x: _sqrt(cancel(x))` would be better. By doing this you are basically saying, "Whenever I use sqrt I want to make sure there are no factors un-cancelled in the expression."